# C# unable to use background workers to use a while loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, label

I'm using a C# form and I essentially want to update a label for every second of the current time. Obviously the UI thread is getting in the way and stuff so I resorted to background workers and I'm sitting here scratching my head trying to update my label every second. I've tried using a while loop in several locations but it won't work. I'm obviously doing something wrong... Any solutions?

Code:

MainForm.Designer.cs:

```
using System;
namespace alarmClock
{
partial class MainForm
{
    System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            if (components != null) {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public static DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    public static string time = now.ToLongTimeString();

    public void setRealHour() {
        hour.Text = time[0].ToString() + time[1].ToString();
    }
    public void setRealMinute() {
        minute.Text = time[3].ToString() + time[4].ToString();
    }
    public void setRealSecond() {
        second.Text = time[6].ToString() + time[7].ToString();
    }

    public void setHourTime() {
        setHour.Text = MainForm.setH.ToString();
        if(MainForm.setH < 10) {
            setHour.Text = "0" + MainForm.setH.ToString();
        }
        if(MainForm.setH > 24) {
            MainForm.setH=0;
            setHour.Text = "0" + MainForm.setH.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void setMinuteTime() {
        setMinute.Text = MainForm.setM.ToString();
        if(MainForm.setM < 10) {
            setMinute.Text = "0" + MainForm.setM.ToString();
        }
        if(MainForm.setM > 60) {
            MainForm.setM=0;
            setMinute.Text = "0" + MainForm.setM.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void setSecondTime() {
        setSecond.Text = MainForm.setS.ToString();
        if(MainForm.setS < 10) {
            setSecond.Text = "0" + MainForm.setS.ToString();
        }
        if(MainForm.setS > 60) {
            MainForm.setS=0;
            setSecond.Text = "0" + MainForm.setS.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.minute = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.hour = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.second = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.checkboxTime = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox();
        this.delTime = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.tableLayoutPanel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.tableLayoutPanel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.setHour = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.setMinute = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.setSecond = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.tableLayoutPanel4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.subHour = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.addHour = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.subMin = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.addMin = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.subSec = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.addSec = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.setTime = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.addTime = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.bgwM = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        this.bgwS = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        this.bgwH = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.SuspendLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.SuspendLayout();
        this.setTime.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.tableLayoutPanel1, "tableLayoutPanel1");
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.minute, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.hour, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.second, 2, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
        // 
        // minute
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.minute, "minute");
        this.minute.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.minute.Name = "minute";
        // 
        // hour
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.hour, "hour");
        this.hour.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.hour.Name = "hour";
        // 
        // second
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.second, "second");
        this.second.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.second.Name = "second";
        // 
        // checkboxTime
        // 
        this.checkboxTime.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.checkboxTime, "checkboxTime");
        this.checkboxTime.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.checkboxTime.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.checkboxTime.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
                                resources.GetString("checkboxTime.Items"),
                                resources.GetString("checkboxTime.Items1")});
        this.checkboxTime.Name = "checkboxTime";
        this.checkboxTime.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.CheckboxTimeSelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // delTime
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.delTime, "delTime");
        this.delTime.Name = "delTime";
        this.delTime.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.delTime.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DelTimeClick);
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel2
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.tableLayoutPanel2, "tableLayoutPanel2");
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel3, 0, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel4, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.Name = "tableLayoutPanel2";
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel3
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.tableLayoutPanel3, "tableLayoutPanel3");
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this.setHour, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this.setMinute, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this.setSecond, 2, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.Name = "tableLayoutPanel3";
        // 
        // setHour
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.setHour, "setHour");
        this.setHour.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.setHour.Name = "setHour";
        // 
        // setMinute
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.setMinute, "setMinute");
        this.setMinute.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.setMinute.Name = "setMinute";
        // 
        // setSecond
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.setSecond, "setSecond");
        this.setSecond.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.setSecond.Name = "setSecond";
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel4
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.tableLayoutPanel4, "tableLayoutPanel4");
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.subHour, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.addHour, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.subMin, 2, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.addMin, 3, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.subSec, 4, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.addSec, 5, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Name = "tableLayoutPanel4";
        // 
        // subHour
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.subHour, "subHour");
        this.subHour.Name = "subHour";
        this.subHour.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.subHour.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SubHourClick);
        // 
        // addHour
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.addHour, "addHour");
        this.addHour.Name = "addHour";
        this.addHour.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.addHour.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.AddHourClick);
        // 
        // subMin
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.subMin, "subMin");
        this.subMin.Name = "subMin";
        this.subMin.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.subMin.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SubMinClick);
        // 
        // addMin
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.addMin, "addMin");
        this.addMin.Name = "addMin";
        this.addMin.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.addMin.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.AddMinClick);
        // 
        // subSec
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.subSec, "subSec");
        this.subSec.Name = "subSec";
        this.subSec.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.subSec.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SubSecClick);
        // 
        // addSec
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.addSec, "addSec");
        this.addSec.Name = "addSec";
        this.addSec.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.addSec.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.AddSecClick);
        // 
        // setTime
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.setTime, "setTime");
        this.setTime.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
        this.setTime.Controls.Add(this.addTime);
        this.setTime.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel2);
        this.setTime.Name = "setTime";
        this.setTime.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // addTime
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.addTime, "addTime");
        this.addTime.Name = "addTime";
        this.addTime.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.addTime.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.AddTimeClick);
        // 
        // bgwM
        // 
        this.bgwM.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.BgwMDoWork);
        // 
        // bgwS
        // 
        this.bgwS.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.BgwSDoWork);
        // 
        // bgwH
        // 
        this.bgwH.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.BgwHDoWork);
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        this.Controls.Add(this.setTime);
        this.Controls.Add(this.delTime);
        this.Controls.Add(this.checkboxTime);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.PerformLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.PerformLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.setTime.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.setTime.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
    }
    private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bgwH;
    private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bgwS;
    private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bgwM;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button addTime;
    System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox setTime;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button addSec;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button subSec;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button addMin;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button subMin;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button addHour;
    System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel4;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label setSecond;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label setMinute;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label setHour;
    System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel3;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button subHour;
    System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel2;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button delTime;
    System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox checkboxTime;
    System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label second;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label hour;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label minute;

    void BgwHDoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        setRealHour();
    }

    void BgwMDoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        setRealMinute();
    }

    void BgwSDoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        setRealSecond();
    }
}
}
```

MainForm.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace alarmClock
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public static int setH = 0;
    public static int setM = 0;
    public static int setS = 0;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bgwH.RunWorkerAsync();
        bgwM.RunWorkerAsync();
        bgwS.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    void DelTimeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void SubHourClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setH--;
        setHourTime();
    }

    void AddHourClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setH++;
        setHourTime();
    }

    void SubMinClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setM--;
        setMinuteTime();
    }

    void AddMinClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setM++;
        setMinuteTime();
    }

    void SubSecClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setS--;
        setSecondTime();
    }

    void AddSecClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setS++;
        setSecondTime();
    }

    void AddTimeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    void CheckboxTimeSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: From the code, it looks like you're making a countdown timer — in which case using `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` or `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` would be more appropriate. In both cases, listen to the `Tick` event

Comment: background worker doesn't help you with this, you still have to synchronise with the ui thread. If your ui thread isn't responsive to  the tick, then may be you should at look at moving whatever is blocking to the background worker

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy noted in the comments, a `Timer` would be a better choice.

For completeness, if you still wanted to use a `BackgroundWorker`, due to some other reason, you will need to use `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress()` method.  Any UI work must be done on the main UI thread.  Using a BackgroundWorker you need to use the Reporting event handler to get your callback back on the main Thread.

You need to ensure `BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress` is set to TRUE.  This is not by default.   Then move your label set method into an Event Handler on `ProgressChanged`

Comment: I'm using the timer class now but when I give a value to lets say second.Text, even if it is in the timer method, it will only update once. Unlike to other attempts however, it does appear to do one update at least because it starts off at "00 00 00" and then after half a second (I've set the interval to 500) it will update to the time. It won't update from there though and I'm sure I've used the right code.

Comment: @Hayden Start another question, post the code in the tick event handler.